# Expected value of $1+1+1+\cdots+1$ (with $n$ "$1$"s) if each '$+$' is independently deleted with probability $1/2$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Problem from an old exam:

> We have a sequence of symbols $1+1+1+1+1+\cdots+1+1$, consisting of $n$ ones and $n-1$ plus signs. Each of the plus signs is independently deleted with a probability of $\frac{1}{2}$. Let $X$ be the value of the resulting expression. For example, if $n=5$ and we delete all the plus signs except the second one, then $X=11+111=122$.

> (a) Calculate $E(X)$.
> (b) Provide a formula for $\operatorname{Var}(X)$. It suffices to provide a formula that is a sum of a polynomial number of terms in compact form (such a sum does not need to be calculated).

For $n = 2$, the expected value should be $ \frac{11+2}{2} = 6.5 $,
for $n = 3$ it should be $\frac{3+12+12+111}{4} = 34.5 $,
for $n = 4$ it should be $\frac{4+13+13+13+22+112+112+1111}{8} = 175 $.

The only thing that comes to my mind is something like $\mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{E}[X_i],$ where $\mathbb{E}[X_i] = 1 + \sum_{j=1}^{i-1}10^j\cdot\frac{1}{2^j}.$

But this obviously gives results that are too large.
How can I approach it?

Comment: For $n =2$, it should be $\frac{11 + 2}{2} = 6.5$.

Comment: Of course. I have fixed it. Thank you @MXXZ.

Comment: +1, and I'm glad something like this was never on _my_ old exams! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $X_k$ be the result of doing your operation on the sum of the last $k+1$ $1$'s.  If the first $+$ that is retained is the $j$'th, then $X_n = (10^j-1)/9 + X_{n-j}$.  Thus
$$ \mathbb E[X_n] = \sum_{j=1}^n 2^{-j} \left(\frac{10^j-1}{9} + \mathbb E[X_{n-j}]\right) + 2^{-n} \frac{10^{n+1}-1}{9} $$

It looks like
$$ \mathbb E[X_n] = \frac{45}{32} 5^n - \frac{n}{8} - \frac{13}{32} $$ and indeed this satisfies the equation.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to deal with this sum in terms of indicator random variables. For each interval $[i,j] \subseteq [1,n]$ where $i<j$ are integers, let $X_{ij} = 1$ if all the $+$ signs between the $i^{\text{th}}$ and $j^{\text{th}}$ $1$'s are omitted. For example, in $1 + 11 + 111$, we have $X_{23} = 1$, $X_{45} = 1$, $X_{56} = 1$, and $X_{46}=1$.

The contribution that the $i^{\text{th}}$ $1$ makes to the sum is equal to $$1 + 9 X_{i,i+1} + 90 X_{i,i+2} + 900 X_{i,i+3} + \dots + 0.9 \cdot 10^{n-i} X_{i,n}.$$ The idea is that each term after the first is a "correction term". By default, the $1$ contributes $1$ to the sum. But if $X_{i,i+1}=1$, it says, "No, actually the contribution is $1+9=10$". But if $X_{i,i+2}=1$, it says, "No, actually the contribution is $10+90=100$". And so on.

The expected value of $X_{i,j}$ is $2^{i-j}$, so the expected value of the sum above is $$1 + 0.9\left(5 + 25 + 125 + \dots + 5^{n-i}\right) = \frac{9 \cdot 5^{n-i} - 1}{8}.$$ This is the expected contribution from the $i^{\text{th}}$ $1$. Therefore the total expected value is $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{9 \cdot 5^{n-i} - 1}{8} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{9 \cdot 5^k - 1}{8} = \frac98 \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 5^k - \frac n8 = \frac9{32}(5^n-1) - \frac n8.$$

In principle, we could use this approach to compute the variance, though I really don't want to. When $[a,b) \cap [c,d) = \varnothing$, the indicator random variables $X_{ab}$ and $X_{cd}$ are independent; otherwise, their product is equal to $X_{\min\{a,b\},\max\{c,d\}}$ and we can use that to compute their covariance...

Answer (score 3):

Three very nice answers have already been given to compute the expectation. My personal favourite is alex.peter’s matrix approach, and it also seems most amenable to extending it to the variance. (I’ll be adopting its notation.)

For the variance, we need the expectation of $X_n^2$. So far we had $1$ constant entry and $2$ linear entries in the state vector; now we need to add $3$ quadratic entries for $S^2$, $dS$ and $d^2$. The initial state vector is now

$$
\left[S_1^2,d_1S_1,d_1^2,S_1,d_1,1\right]=[0,0,1,0,1,1]\;.
$$

If we add $+1$, the new transitions are $S_{n+1}^2=\left(S_n+d_n\right)^2=S_n^2+2d_nS_n+d_n^2$ and $d_{n+1}S_{n+1}=S_n+d_n$ and $d_{n+1}^2=1$, described in matrix form by

$$
\left[S_{n+1}^2,d_{n+1}S_{n+1},d_{n+1}^2,S_{n+1},d_{n+1},1\right]=\left[S_n^2,d_nS_n,d_n^2,S_n,d_n,1\right]\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0&0&0\\2&0&0&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&1&0&0\\0&1&0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0&1&1\end{bmatrix}\;.
$$

If we add $1$, the new transitions are $S_{n+1}^2=S_n^2$ and $d_{n+1}S_{n+1}=(10d_n+1)S_n=10d_nS_n+S_n$ and $d_{n+1}^2=(10d_n+1)^2=100d_n^2+20d_n+1$, described in matrix form by

$$
\left[S_{n+1}^2,d_{n+1}S_{n+1},d_{n+1}^2,S_{n+1},d_{n+1},1\right]=\left[S_n^2,d_nS_n,d_n^2,S_n,d_n,1\right]\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0&0&0\\0&10&0&0&0&0\\0&0&100&0&0&0\\0&1&0&1&0&0\\0&0&20&0&10&0\\0&0&1&0&1&1\end{bmatrix}\;.
$$

So we now have

$$
T_1+T_2=\begin{bmatrix}2&0&0&0&0&0\\2&10&0&0&0&0\\1&0&100&0&0&0\\0&2&0&2&0&0\\0&1&20&1&10&0\\0&0&2&0&2&2\end{bmatrix}\;.
$$

The expected value of $X_n^2$ is

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathsf E\left[X_n^2\right]
&=&
\frac1{2^{n-1}}S_n^2
\\
&=&
\frac1{2^{n-1}}[0,0,1,0,1,1]\begin{bmatrix}2&0&0&0&0&0\\2&10&0&0&0&0\\1&0&100&0&0&0\\0&2&0&2&0&0\\0&1&20&1&10&0\\0&0&2&0&2&2\end{bmatrix}^{n-1}\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0&0&0\\2&0&0&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&1&0&0\\0&1&0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0&1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}
\\
&=&
\frac1{2^{n-1}}[0,0,1,0,1,1]\begin{bmatrix}2&0&0&0&0&0\\2&10&0&0&0&0\\1&0&100&0&0&0\\0&2&0&2&0&0\\0&1&20&1&10&0\\0&0&2&0&2&2\end{bmatrix}^{n-1}\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\1\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}\;,
\end{eqnarray*}

which [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%7B%7B0%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C1%7D%7D%20*%20%7B%7B2%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B2%2C10%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C100%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C2%2C0%2C2%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C20%2C1%2C10%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C2%2C0%2C2%2C2%7D%7D%5E%28n-1%29%20*%20%7B%7B1%7D%2C%7B2%7D%2C%7B1%7D%2C%7B0%7D%2C%7B0%7D%2C%7B0%7D%7D&dataset=) evaluates to

$$\frac{19208n^2+1764\left(49\cdot5^n+76\right)n-218491\cdot5^n+121\cdot2^{n+8}\cdot25^n+187515}{2^9\cdot7^4}\;.$$

Thus, the variance is

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathsf{Var}\left[X_n\right]
&=&
\mathsf E\left[X_n^2\right]-\mathsf E\left[X_n\right]^2
\\
&=&
\frac{19208n^2+1764\left(49\cdot5^n+76\right)n-218491\cdot5^n+121\cdot2^{n+8}\cdot25^n+187515}{2^9\cdot7^4}
\\
&&-\left(\frac{9\cdot5^n−4n−9}{32}\right)^2
\\[8pt]
&=&
\frac{25^n(121\cdot2^{n+9}-194481)+9604\cdot5^n(36n-5)+243(392n+743)}{2^{10}\cdot7^4}\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

The first few values are

\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathsf{Var}\left[X_1\right]&=&0\;,\\
\mathsf{Var}\left[X_2\right]&=&\frac{81}4\;,\\
\mathsf{Var}\left[X_3\right]&=&\frac{7857}4\;,\\
\mathsf{Var}\left[X_4\right]&=&126927\;.
\end{eqnarray*}